# Can`t render django form in the template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

after reading the [doc on django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/forms/), I tried to build my own form but the form just won`t render in the template. I also went through similar questions on stackoverflow but no solutions can solve my problem.
I have this simple form based on model. Here`s the snippet of my code.
The model:

```
class Tweet(activity.Activity, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #...
```

The form:

```
class TweetForm(ModelForm):
    #text = forms.CharField(label = 'Tweet', max_length = 100)
    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = '__all__'
```

The view:

```
def user(request, user_name):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
    form = TweetForm()
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=user_name)
    feeds = feed_manager.get_user_feed(user.id)
    activities = feeds.get(limit=25)['results']
    activities = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
    context = {
        'activities': activities,
        'user': user,
        'login_user': request.user,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'look/user.html', context)
```

The html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Tweet" />
```

Actually, I **could** render the form in the python shell so there`s nothing wrong with the form. However, I found out that the problem lies here:

```
form = TweetForm()
#...
context = {
    'activities': activities,
    'user': user,
    'login_user': request.user,
    'form': form   #see although the form is passed to the context,
}                  #I can`t access variable form in the html
return render(request, 'look/user.html', context)
```

The key/value pair `{'form':form}` in the `context` is not rendered normally and that`s why the `{{ form }}` doesn`t work. But any other variables in the `context` works just fine.
It really bothers me and I couldn`t figure out why the context is not working. Thanks in advance for any ideas.
P.S.
I tried this:

```
{% if form %} form is true
{% else %} form is false
{% endif %}
```

in my html template and the result is `form is false` which indicates that the `form` variable is not passed through context or something I can`t explain happened. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: How you are running the `runserver` ?

Comment: `runserver` works just fine except the form is not rendered and there is only a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what went wrong... And it`s something silly. I actually rendered the `user.html` in another function so anything I did in method `user` is not working. After instantiating a `form` instance in the *right* view method, the `TweetForm` is rendered successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have rendered my form using a loop in my template:

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
                <br/>
                <br/>
            {% endfor %}
```

This displays the form correctly in my project.

Comment: The things is although I have added form in the context, the `form` variable is not available in the html template.

Comment: @scotthou  Hmm.  I'm not sure what it could be.  I take it you have accidentally commented out the form field on the code here but not in the real code itself?

Comment: \@cmakie21 that\`s because I tried to create a form which is not based on existing model to see whether the problem is about the `ModelForm`. Turned out it\`s not.